# Is there locational damage when hunting?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-40th-anniversary

I'm using the starter rifle, and I have yet to take down a deer or buffalo while hunting. I've tried shooting in the center of the torso and in the head, but neither location kills the animal.

Due to the reload speed of the starter rifle, one shot is all I can get off before the animal runs off the screen.

I have a feeling I just need to wait until I can buy a better gun, but my question still stands:

**Is there locational damage when hunting?**